# Direct self-reference leading to cycle error with a FetchType.LAZY

Tags: json, spring-boot, hibernate, fetch, many-to-one

I have a model with a lot of @ManyToOne when I try to make a request, I've a recursive Json.

So, I put some FetchType.EAGER like this and it works:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "comp_doc", referencedColumnName = "comp_doc")
    public CompDoc  getCompDoc() {
        return CompDoc;
    }
```

But I don't need all of the @ManyToOne for a couple of requests. So I've tried to change the FetchType to LAZY like this :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "comp_doc", referencedColumnName = "comp_doc")
        public CompDoc  getCompDoc() {
            return CompDoc;
        }
```

At this point, if I don't need the datas inside the @ManyToOne, normally, they'll be excluded from the Json.

But instead of this (which is my goal), I've now an error:

> Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain:
> java.util.ArrayList[6021]->org.test.test.model.Document["documentByDocId"]

Why this error appera with a LAZY and not with a EAGER?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are trying to serialize something to JSON with Jackson that has cycles. That's not supported though. The fetch mode shouldn't make a difference here I think but this is definitely either a data problem, or a configuration issue. Maybe you should try to ignore some of the many-to-one associations that you don't need in your JSON by annotating them with `@JsonIgnore`